# Is there a straightforward way to use Tailwind CSS with Quarto as a base theme for a blog?

Tags: tailwind-css, quarto, tailwind-ui, python-markdown

I want to use tailwind instead of Bootstrap in all the app, so I used `include-in-header`. I used the [example](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/utility-first#why-not-just-use-inline-styles)  from the Tailwind docs:

```
---
title: "Fake app"
pagetitle: "Fake page title"
subtitle: "Fake role"

format:
  html:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@3.4.1/lib/index.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@3.4.1/base.min.css">
---



::: {.py-8 .px-8 .max-w-sm .mx-auto .bg-white .rounded-xl .shadow-lg .space-y-2 .sm:py-4 .sm:flex .sm:items-center .sm:space-y-0 .sm:space-x-6}
<img class="block mx-auto h-24 rounded-full sm:mx-0 sm:shrink-0" src="/img/erin-lindford.jpg" alt="Woman's Face" />

::: {.text-center .space-y-2 .sm:text-left}
::: {.space-y-0.5}
Erin Lindford
::: {.text-lg .text-black .font-semibold}
Product Engineer
::: {.text-slate-500 .font-medium}
:::

<button class="px-4 py-1 text-sm text-purple-600 font-semibold rounded-full border border-purple-200 hover:text-white hover:bg-purple-600 hover:border-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-purple-600 focus:ring-offset-2">Message</button>
:::
:::
```

This is the output

[image]

As you can see, the code snippet I took from from Tailwind CSS official website and put it in my Quarto `index.qmd` file doesn't work, and unfortunately breaks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use the [Play CDN](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn), not the random CSS and JS files you included:

```yaml
format:
  html:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
```

Though do be aware that:

> The Play CDN is designed for development purposes only, and is not the best choice for production.

Otherwise, you could consider integrating the Tailwind CLI, [via NPM](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) or as a [standalone executable](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli). The Tailwind build process is language-agnostic so it should work with your project (if you are using the standalone executable, substitute `npx tailwindcss` with path to the executable):

1. Create a Tailwind configuration:

   ```bash
   $ npx tailwindcss init
   ```
2. Include file paths/globs that cover source code that contain Tailwind class names using [the `content` option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration):

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     content: [
       './path/to/index.qmd',
     ],
     theme: {
       extend: {},
     },
     plugins: [],
   }
   ```
3. Have an input CSS file:

   ```css
   /* input.css */
   @tailwind base;
   @tailwind components;
   @tailwind utilities;
   ```
4. Run a compilation:

   ```bash
   npx tailwind --input path/to/input.css --output path/to/output.css
   ```
5. Include the `output.css` file in your project:

   ```yaml
   format:
     html: 
       css: path/to/output.css
   ```

Comment: thanks, but when I put the CDN link, it overrides my navbar and I lose the links that exist in my navbar for navigation... like contact page and posts, etc

Comment: Yes, that could happen. You'd probably need to consolidate the styling of your HTML pages after integrating Tailwind – it is not a drop-in replacement for Bootstrap.

Comment: Alright, do you have any links on how I could fix this ? Btw, thank you, I'll accept your answer as a solution =)

Comment: I don't have any links on how you could fix that.